# I am trying this code for finding the missing member in a list..but it doesn't work

Tags: python

```
list = [['a', (1,1)], ['a', (1,2)], ['a', (1,4)], ['a', (1,5)]]

for i in list:
    print "the i is ", i
    print i[0]   # 'a'
    print i[1]   # (1, 1)
    n = 'a'
    v = (1,1)
    #n = re.search(r'[a-z]', i[0])
    #v = (v[0], (v[1] + 1))
    print "just", i[1]
    print "trying ", v
    for j in i:  
        if (j[0] != n):
            v = (1, 1)
            n = i[0]
        if (i[1] != v):
            print v
            raise ValueError, '[%s, %s] is missing' %(i[0], (i[1][0], i[1][1]-1))

        v = (v[0], (v[1] + 1))
```

The value doesn't seem to change after the first iteration i.e. it remains to `(1,1)`, which I can see however what needs to be done so that it reports the missing item in a list i.e. in this example list it is `['a', (1, 3)]`. Generally, the code starts with `['a', (1,1)]` for detection of its missing in a list and so it follows each item in a sequence

Comment: This code is pretty convoluted. What is it actually trying to do?

Answer (score 0):

You want to put

```
v = (1,1)
```

*outside* of the for loop (and you don't want to put `v = (1, 1)` in the `if (j[0] != n)` statement either). Otherwise it will be set back to `(1, 1)` every time.

ETA: Having said that, this is not a good way to solve the problem. Why not do something like:

```
for i in range(1, 6):
    if ["a", (1, i)] not in list:
        raise ValueError, '["a", (1, %s)] is missing' % i
```

Comment: I had tried that and it shows that ValueError: [a, (1, 0)] is missing

Comment: if my list = [['a', (1,2)], ['a', (1,3)],['a', (1,4)], ['a', (1,5)]] it should report that ['a',(1,1)] is missing..if my list =  [['a', (1,1)], ['a', (1,3)], ['a', (1,4)]] it should report ['a',(1,2)] is missing and so on. I am trying to test for the missing items

Comment: the list should not be restricted to ['a', (1,5)]..It can have ['a',(2, 1)],['a', (2, 2)], ['a', (3,1)] ['a', (3, 2)] ['a', (3, 4)] and so on.. however they all come in a sequence and so these items should also be made to test

Answer (score 0):

Ive seen this repeatedly asked so here is a complete example

```
def ListToDict(l):
    d = {}
    for itm in l:
        if  itm[0] not in d:d[itm[0]]=[]
        d[itm[0]].append(itm[1])
    for key in d:
        itm = d[key]
        if isinstance(itm,(list,tuple)) and len(d[key])>0 and isinstance(d[key][0],(tuple,list)):
            d[key] = ListToDict(d[key])
    return d
def ValidateSequences(d):
    if isinstance(d,(tuple,list)):
        return sorted(d) == range(min(d),max(d)+1)
    elif isinstance(d,dict):
        r = {}
        for key in d:
            r[key] = ValidateSequences(d[key])
        return r
my_list = [['a', (1,1)], ['a', (1,2)], ['a', (1,4)], ['a', (1,5)]]
d = ListToDict(my_list)
print "Validated:",ValidateSequences(d)
my_list.append(["a",(1,3)])
d = ListToDict(my_list)
print "Revalidated:",ValidateSequences(d)
```

and the output is

```
Validated: {'a': {1: False}}
Revalidated: {'a': {1: True}}
```